# Is there a way to join multiple strings in value fields when pivoting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, powerquery

I am trying to make a table more readable by making a report.
This table has 3 columns;

1. Staff
2. Task (Each staff could have 0-many tasks)
3. Status (Planned, Started, Finished)

The report would have Staff as the left most column, 3 status as column headings. The values should be task values and if there are many tasks it should be concatenated, say, with a carriage return.

I tried pivoting but it didn't work since the task values are texts. I tried Power Query and it displays errors for every cell where there are more than 1 task.

Is there a way to do this? ...without VBA please.
Thanks

Comment: You can probably do this using Power Query.

Comment: yeah, I was playing around with Power Query and I used the following code:


`code`
Table.Pivot(#"Reordered Columns", List.Distinct(#"Reordered Columns"[Status]), "Status", "Task", Text.Combine)
`code`

This gives me what I want except the values are all concatenated without a delimiter. How can I put one?

Comment: There's an optional `separator` argument for Text.Combine

Comment: that, unfortunately, throws an exception

Comment: I can't help you further with the information you have provided. If you still need some help, I'd suggest you edit your question to provide relevant information so that your problem can be reproduced.  Perhaps the HELP pages for  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you know how to operate Power Query Editor so I will skip the part of how to add data to the editor.

In my solution, I used the following sample data stored in **Table3**.

[image: Sample Data Table3]

Once added data the editor will automatically recognize all data as text.

[image: Query Table3]

My approach is to add a custom column to combine **Staff** and **Status** as below first:

[image: Add Custom Column]

Then I grouped the data by the custom column (**Staff+Status**) with some Advanced Coding. You can do a **Group By** first and then go to **Advanced Editor** to change the formula as below:

```
= Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Staff+Status"}, {{"Task", each Text.Combine([Task],"#(lf)"), type text}})
```

Which will give you the following look:

[image: Grouped]

Then you can **split the custom column** back to Staff and Status separately:
[image: Split Column]

Then you can **pivot the Status column**, set **Task** as the `Values Column`, and in the **Advanced Options** set **Don't Aggregate** as the `Aggregate Value Function`.

[image: Pivot Column]

Then you pretty much finished here, and you can load the query to a worksheet which may look like the following where the **carriage return** seems not working.

[image: No Carriage Return]

In order to '**activate**' carriage return (which is actually **line feed**), you need to select a cell that you want to see carriage return, click somewhere in the formula bar, and you will notice the carriage return is 'activated'.

Copy the format of that cell and paste to the rest of the table using **Format Painter** to get the following:

[image: Final]

If you are unclear about the above step, please read this article: [How to display Power Query results with line feed or carriage return](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/04/16/how-to-display-power-query-results-with-line-feed/)

All done. Cheers :)

By the way here are the codes behind the scene for reference only:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Staff", type text}, {"Task", type text}, {"Status", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Staff+Status", each [Staff]&"+"&[Status]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Staff+Status"}, {{"Task", each Text.Combine([Task],"#(lf)"), type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Staff+Status", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("+", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Staff+Status.1", "Staff+Status.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Staff+Status.1", type text}, {"Staff+Status.2", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type1", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type1"[#"Staff+Status.2"]), "Staff+Status.2", "Task"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Staff+Status.1", "Staff"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```